Has there ever been an accident caused by a laser pointer strike?
As seen in the FAA's Laser Incidents by Year data, the number of laser strike incidents has increased over the years.
I wonder if there has been a strike serious enough to have caused an accident* in the USA or any other country?
* The definition of accident by ICAO is: A person is fatally or seriously injured or the aircraft sustains damage or structural failure or is missing/inaccessible

I believe this one, in the US, would count as an accident, according to ICAO definition:

Partial blindness requiring medical treatment
Nov 20, 2022
Zenith CH 750 Cruzer
Landing at Arlington Airport, Snohomish County, WA


According to records filed in the case, at about 5:00 PM on November 20,2022, [...] points a blue laser pointer at the cockpit of a two-person personal aircraft. The plane was on a track to land at Arlington Airport. The pilot’s eyes were damaged by the laser beam, and he was unable to see his instrument panel. He was able to switch to the backlight on the instrument screen which allowed him to safely land the aircraft. The pilot needed medical treatment for his eye injury.

However there was no investigation by NTSB, and the police report isn't public. This laser strike was neither registered by FAA as an accident nor an incident.
Was the laser strike able to cause an accident? According to the pilot:

If I had been flying an older aircraft without the instrument visual aids, I likely would not have survived.

and according to the judge, to the defendant:

You almost killed this man.

A second laser strike, less harmful, was attempted at another aircraft flown by a student, the instructor was able to take pictures:

(Source)
Based on news:

Pilot blindly lands plane after eyes are damaged by laser aimed into cockpit

Snohomish County man who aimed laser at two small planes sentenced to prison


